# Laravel Installation Error - Blank Page After Install

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I've installed Laravel on a EC2 instance. All permissions have been written and all necessary solutions have been installed. I can access the Laravel directory fine, however when accessing the `public` folder, all I'm getting is a blank white page. No errors and no "welcome" page that I normally should be seeing. However, this is the error being logged on the server:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mrktpop/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/mrktpop/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Line 17 of autoload.php is as follows:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Composer Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Anyone experience this and can extend an offering hand? No `/vendor` folder exists anywhere on the directory...

Comment: Have you used composer to install the dependencies?  Composer brings in all the dependencies, puts them in the vendor/ directory and then creates and autoload.php file.  If you don't know what this is, [visit the composer website](http://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: Composer is installed... `/vendor` folder in the root directory (i.e. mrktpop)...should I install in `public`?

Comment: Ony thing in the `/vendor` folder is a `symfony` folder, nothing else..

Comment: Then all the dependencies aren't installed.  Delete the vendor folder and the composer.lock and try running `composer install`.

Comment: composer.lock? I don't have that file...

Comment: Ran this `$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` then I did, `$ php composer.phar install`, and I got these errors: http://pastebin.com/VsftjWTP

Comment: Aha.  I literally just dealt with this yesterday.  There's a few things you can do.  First, upgrade your PHP to a newer version.  If that doesn't help, try committing your composer.lock file with your repo.  Then when you run `php composer.phar install`, it won't waste memory searching for the newest package.  It will only look for the ones you downloaded locally.  This helps with the memory issue.  You can also increase the memory in your `php.ini` file that PHP is allowed to use. Essentially what's happening (I think) is PHP is running out of memory.

Comment: No idea what your referring to about `composer.lock`...as I don't see that file anywhere. Secondly, no idea what you mean by much of your message, instruction wise. I'll try changing the memory limit in my `php.ini` file though.

Comment: Did just notice when I install composer globally, all the files show up. Just not when I install in the var/www/ root I need it in...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43551/discussion-between-searsaw-and-mike-barwick)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it's a memory issue.  The options aren't great if you're not familiar with command line, but they work.  Try upgrading PHP.  Increase memory PHP is allowed to use in php.ini.  Try committing your `composer.lock` file to your repo, pulling it to the EC2 instance, and then running `composer install`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I increased the memory in `php.ini` as you requested (increased it to 1GB) and also used a non-micro instance on EC2. That seemed to help!